# Handle click item in Recycleview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a **horizontal recycleview** inside **vertical recycleview**.

and i add list **cardview** inside **horizontal recycleview**.

How to get the item information when click on the item on main activity?

Thank you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private AlbumsVerticalAdapter adapter;
        private List<Album> albumList;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            initCollapsingToolbar();
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            albumList = new ArrayList<>();
            adapter = new AlbumsVerticalAdapter(this, albumList);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        private void initCollapsingToolbar() {}

        private void prepareAlbums() {}
    }


public class AlbumsVerticalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlbumsVerticalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Album> albumList;

    //.............

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Album album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getName());
        AlbumsHorizontalAdapter itemListDataAdapter = new AlbumsHorizontalAdapter(mContext, albumList);
        holder.recycler_view_list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.recycler_view_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.recycler_view_list.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Create callbacks() and interfaces for this

Comment: https://svn.code.sf.net/p/allandroidexample/svn/CardView

this my example code. you can checkout it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would be better to implement `OnClickListener` on your `ViewHolder` class and add the listener to your desired views.

Just in `onBindViewHolder(...)` add `setOnClickListener(...)` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //... 

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), position + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code the VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter has a `List<Albums>` and each Album in this list will require a HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter to hold another `List<Albums>`.

In your VerticalRecylerViewAdapter create `VerticalClickListener` which will be implemented by your activity. Inside HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter create `HorizontalClickListener` which will be implemented by your VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter for each Album. When creating the HorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter for each Album, pass in the **vertical** position as well. Then, when a cardview is clicked, the `HorizontalClickListener` can return the vertical position of the adapter and also the horizontal position of the cardview. The VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter will return the vertical and horizontal positions to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create an interface like :

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position)
}
```

Declare on global :

```
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
```

Next, you need a contructor like :

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, List data, OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener){
//...
this.mOnItemClickListener= mOnItemClickListener;
```

}

And in onBindViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FolderViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  //....
  holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,position);    
        }
    });
```

}

Finally, you can implement Callback in class use adapter like :

```
public class A extends AppCombatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
 //exist code
    @Override
    onItemClick(View view, int position){
     // Do something with view + position
  }

 }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your support. But i want to get the position of cardview in horizontal Recycleview

Answer (score 0):

```
 /Just try to implement the below code Snippet/

 First make an Interface Class "RecyclerView_ItemClickListener"

 public interface RecyclerView_ItemClickListener
 {
  void onClick(View view, int position);

  void onItemClick(View view, int position);
 }

 Then use this class in your Activity/Fragment and  inside Adapter.

 How to Implement in Adapter class:

 private RecyclerView_ItemClickListener clickListener;

 public void setClickListener(RecyclerView_ItemClickListener itemClickListener)
 {
    this.clickListener = itemClickListener;
 }

 public void SetOnItemClickListener(final RecyclerView_ItemClickListener mItemClickListener)
 {
    this.clickListener = mItemClickListener;
 }

Implement implements View.OnClickListener inside MyViewHolder Method 
of Adapter

 Example like this: class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener

itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


Then put the below code

@Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        if (clickListener != null)
        {
            clickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());

            clickListener.onItemClick(view,getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

After that implements RecyclerView_ItemClickListener inside your 
Activity/Fragment

in OnCreate:

your_Adapter.setClickListener(this);

your_Adapter.SetOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position)
{}

@Override
public void onItemClick(View view, int position)
{

}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your support. But i want to get the position of cardview in horizontal Recycleview

Answer (score 0):

Create an inteface

```
public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(View view, int position)
}
```

Add a parametrized constuctor in your adapter  **AlbumsVerticalAdapter**

```
private OnItemClickListener mOnviewItemClickListener;
public AlbumsVerticalAdapter(Context context, List data, OnItemClickListener mOItemClickListener){
//...
this.mOnItemClickListener= mOnItemClickListener;
```

Now add this line in your in OnBinderViewHolder method inside adapter class

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final FolderViewHolder holder, final int position) {
  //....
  mholder.mimageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnItemClickListener){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v,position);    
        }
    });
}
```

Implement this interface in your Activity and use onClick of the item

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCombatActivity implements AlbumsVerticalAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        onItemClick(View view, int position){
         // write your code 
      }

     }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your support.
But i want to get the position of cardview in horizontal Recycleview