# Does each class have to have it's own OnClickListener?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Total Android beginner here...

I have an Activity with an OnClick Listener as in this example: [Multiple Buttons `OnClickListener()` android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905086/multiple-buttons-onclicklistener-android)

And now I'm setting up a listener on Floating Action Button in a different activity. What I'm not sure about is whether it is possible to use that same listener, or does each class have to have it's own?

```
ACTIVITY #1 // a regular activity
public class Requests extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {...}

ACTIVITY #2 // A RecyclerView, CardView type activity
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {...}
```

I'd really like to have one Listener to handle the cardview click events, as well as the Floating Action Button.

Comment: if it's only for buttons, you can specify which method it's supposed to execute in the xml: `andorid:onClick=methodName`

Comment: If those classes has the same functionality then yes you can implement the same OnClickListener otherwise you need to implement the different listener in order to do the different task

Comment: @Century I don't think the OP is asking this. If you would have read the question he is asking to implement one listener to handle the different click events

Comment: Or else you can do one thing you can write a single class to implement listener and based on the button id you can create another activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in general you can use the same listener for multiple buttons. if they are in different activities , you can write a seperate class that implements View.OnClickListener . Like this:

```
public class MyButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.oneButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.twoButton:
        // do your code
        break;

    case R.id.threeButton:
        // do your code
        break;// default method for handling onClick Events..
}
```

}

Then you just have to set your button listener like `button.setOnClicklistener(new MyOnClickListener());`

If your buttons are all doing the same action, you wont need the switch-case block.

Creating a seperate listener class is not a bad idea at all BUT: you should try to implement one for each activty to keep an overview over your button actions.

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: This approach makes sense to me. But could you please explain something else... what if the one click is from a "card" in a cardview and the other click is from a menu option, and the third from a button in a view. I'm not sure that all three event sources would be accessible through the `public void onClick(View v)`. Unless I'm not understanding what the `View v` reference means....?

Comment: @Maxcot all those UI elements you mentioned extend the `View` class. Will have specified them in an XML file, that belongs to an activity or works as a ListView item. However, in the XML you have to declare a unique ID for every element, you want to behave in a seperate way. All these IDs are accessable throu the `R` class. So it is possible to access them in a onClickListener class. Hope you could follow my explanation

Comment: "... all those UI elements you mentioned extend the View class..." Ah, well, that explains that nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snipet mentioned in the link below

[Handle click item in Recycleview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337862/handle-click-item-in-recycleview/46338145#46338145)

In that onClick and onItemClick Override listener you can implement both  Floating Action Button and cardview click events position wise

Answer (score 0):

To perform same operation on click event of different view or viewGroup implement an anonymous class for OnClickListener as

```
View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener= new View.OnClickListener() {  
 @Override public void onClick(View v) {    /*do your code */ }};
```

or call it in your activity as

```
 mbutton.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);   
    mcardView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```