# about making offline dictionary

Tags: java, android

Before asking things, i am really sorry for all developers who are studying well, making well.
 Because person such like me would not be qualified in here to even ask a question. but i really, sincerly need help from people like you.

Currently i am studying in HUFS(Hankuk University of Foreign Studies) South korea.
My major is Polish(language in poland) and eventhough we already have a paper dictionary which were made by our professors but it is not that much useful because it is big and heavy to take everyday.

Do for my big plan, I want to make a dictionary app for my senior and also for my other friends who learn polish and more people who want to study polish alone.

But sadly I have never studied a JAVA in my whole life, maybe only the chance I could see JAVA in my life would be when I played minecraft.

So I decided to study as much as I can do alone with the book in library, but still so much hard.
 But i dont want to ask whole help for the project because it would be a very rude thing to ask.
 Also I know helping one person is also matter of money... ( in korea everyone, asked me about if i help you how much could you pay??)

Here is the 2 Big question about my project.

**1. What do i need? 2. How Can I?**

For the first model of my app, i think i might gonna add only simple searching system:
main menu -> button click -> (main activity changes) -> search screen comes out.
when the search screen comes out , there is search bar in the top , and 
other part will be result list.

for this part i will use autocompletetext mechanism.

the problem is next.

if i searched

on the search bar, 
at the search result list, there might appear 
1. Red
2. Reply
3. Read

like this.

but if i click word  can i connect to a new acitivity that shows word 's meaning?

all youtube videos only shows when you search it, the word comes out and it's all.

i want something like this

1. I put a word "Re" on the search bar
2. automatically finding words that contain "Re" from my db.
3. click on of word that is on result list.
4. IF, CLASSIFICATION that i put in DB, is "VERB", than open a mainactivity 13
   that has form which can show you pastence, futuretence, have+p.p and meaning
   4-1. if CLASSIFICATION that iput in DB, is "ETC", than open a mainactivity 12
   that has form which only show(loads) meaning and explanation.

my db is like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCggQ.png)

first column is word that is private key.
second column is classification. which will classify if word is
"Verb", "Noun", "ETC", "Adjective", "Adverb"
3rd column is meaning.
4rth column is explanation or some example sentences.
form 5th is just all changeable format of words (dont mind it. it is for loading
some textures when you load certain mainacitivy)

So for the conclusion,
what i want to ask is "IS THERE ANY WAY for me to search, and then click, and then open new activities by giving option with db's "Classification"??"

i need your help.
i dont need money after making this app. i will be putting out for free for every koreans who would like to learn polish my him/herself.

Comment: Please leave out the excuses and pleads from the question. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of posting these here post it on Quora. And google about how to learn android first. There are a bunch of free resources and paid as well. You can go with udacity. Only free courses will be enough to make this app.

Comment: But, yes, you can search. Lookup sqlite full text search for Android, then add a auto complete text view and learn more about starting activities, and you'll be most of the way there... Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably going to have to use a Recycle Views, its the best thing to use for handling click events, there is tons of examples online on using and implementing Recycle Views  but what you are trying to do shouldn't be difficult, check this out -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141701/android-activity-with-a-recyclerview-inflated-by-a-big-arraylist

and -> [Handle click item in Recycleview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46337862/handle-click-item-in-recycleview)